# CAN Communication in QT

Tags: c++, qt, can-bus, socketcan, canutils

I have a specific problem with the CAN communication in QT. It is not a problem to send/write CAN messages, but the readFrame() function in QT doesn't load my received frames. If you are implementing a CAN communication in C++ you can use the read() and write() functions. But in QT it is not supported. In general the read function interrupts the programm until a message is received, how can I do the same in QT?

```
QCanBusFrame frame = device->readFrame();
```

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you connect framesReceived signal to your slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the QT docs:

> Returns the next QCanBusFrame from the queue; otherwise returns an
> empty QCanBusFrame. The returned frame is removed from the queue.
>
> The queue operates according to the FIFO principle.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qcanbusdevice.html#readFrame

Try first calling

```
bool QCanBusDevice::waitForFramesReceived(int msecs)
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qcanbusdevice.html#waitForFramesReceived

and then read frames

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I call the "bool QCanBusDevice::waitForFramesReceived(int msecs)" in QT. In the header file or in mainwindow.cpp.

Comment: `QCanBusFrame frame;
    if (device->waitForFramesReceived(1000)) { frame = device->readFrame();}`

Comment: Most likely, you're reading frames before the buffer has any. Adding a waitforFramesReceived will block execution for a period and then you may call readFrame?

Comment: What is your setup? What is sending and receiving, are you able to confirm that your physical setup is functional?

Comment: Yeah, everthing is working so far. I am monitoring the CAN messages over candump can0. There I receive every message.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Instead of 1000 ms as value you can typ -1 (waitForFramesReceived(-1).Finally, the whole programm will wait for a CAN message.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution was to do this: ` if (device->waitForFramesReceived(-1))` which waits until a frame is received?

Comment: Yes, correct! :)